# Migrating a graphics heavy Java Swing application to the web

Tags: java, swing, applet, java-ee-8

I have a large Java Swing application I'd like to migrate to the web. It makes very heavy use of 2D interactive graphics and also uses Java3D.

It started life as an Applet in Java 1.0 and grew quite considerably. If only applets were still available they'd be perfect for me.

There are so many options I'm not sure which way to turn. But I don't want to end up recoding the whole thing in JavaScript or something. Even the data layer in this is big (dozens of proprietary data types supported) so just rewriting and testing would be a massive project. I there some way that Java EE can run interactive graphics or is it purely back end?

I can deploy it with Webswing (which I highly recommend) but the whole thing sits inside a browser window so it looks clunky. I want a more long term "proper" solution.

Thanks for the help! I have little knowledge of writing web apps.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to convert as much of your project to Open GL (JOGL in Java). At least some web browsers now have access to OGL.